# null container in fragment oncreate method

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show my fragment in another activity. At first everything was fine but after editing code my fragment don't shows up. This is my main activity content XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
        android:name="ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc.CatFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And fragment class:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_front, container, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.size(); i++) {
        CatModel catModel = new CatModel();
        catModel.txt = cat[i];
        catModel.imgid = imgs.get(i);
        arrayList.add(catModel);
    }
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_front, container, false).findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager =
            new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    catAdapter = new CatAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(catAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

Main Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

When I debugging my app the container in fragment class is null. Why is this happening?

Comment: which class or xml file? @quicklearner

Comment: the activity class where you are adding the fragment

Comment: im showing fragment via main activity content xml code that posted at first but i added my main activity too @quicklearner

Comment: you are not adding the fragment class

Comment: what do you mean? @quicklearner

Comment: FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragment =new MyFragment();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content,fragment,"myFragmentTag");
        ft.commit();

Comment: still not showing @quicklearner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `recyclverView` from a newly inflated layout when you should be working with the layout you already inflated previously and assigned to `view`.

This means the view you are returning still has an empty `recyclerView`. To fix this change:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_front, container, false).findViewById(R.id.recycler);
```

To:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
```

so that you use the `recyclerView` associated with the view you are returning.

Comment: You're welcome and nice job also finding your problem and the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem it was  `findviewbyid` in fragment class. I changed this:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_front, container, false).findViewById(R.id.recycler);
```

to this:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
```